# How to find cell address in a table/range with nth value in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula

I need a formula that will output the cell address of the nth value in the table/range shown in the image.  The range is an output of x/y variables that will be continuously changing.  So the nth value, as well as its row/column address, will always be changing as well.

I have used
`=large(D39:N60,1)` to output the nth (1) value of the range, but have not been able to combine with any other functions to output the cell address.

[image: Output of x/y variable calculations]

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `ADDRESS`:

```
=ADDRESS(row, column, 4)
```

---

```
=INDEX(ADDRESS(
 MAX(IF(LARGE(D39:N60, 1)=D39:N60, ROW(39:60), )), 
 MAX(IF(LARGE(D39:N60, 1)=D39:N60, COLUMN(D:N), )), 4))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: As a follow up, is there another formula I can use to output only the Row Number or only the Column of this cell also?

Comment: try: `=INDEX(MAX(IF(LARGE(D39:N60, 1)=D39:N60, ROW(39:60), )))`

Comment: Thank you!  This works.  When I try to use ```COLUMN``` instead of ```ROW```, it outputs as a number rather than letter.  Is there a fix?

Comment: for column try: `=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(ADDRESS(1, MAX(IF(LARGE(D39:N60, 1)=D39:N60, COLUMN(D:N), )), 4)), 1, )`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you again